# QueryDSL - Cast boolean to number in MySQL

Tags: querydsl

I used to work with JPAQuery in QueryDSL.

Now, I need to make a query with some aggregations using a boolean field (tinyint(1) in MySQL)

Here's my code 
(I've shortened the request) :

```
JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(em);
QMyEntity myEntity = QMyEntity.myEntity;

NumberExpression<Integer> nExprRefused = myEntity.isRefused.castToNum(Integer.class);
NumberExpression<Integer> nExprAccepted = myEntity.isAccepted.castToNum(Integer.class);

return query.from(myEntity)
        .groupBy(myEntity.otherField)
        .list(Projections.constructor(
                       MyProjection.class
                       , nExprAccepted.sum()
                       , nExprRefused.sum()
                       , myEntity.otherField)
                       )
             );
```

The problem is that the cast is made like this :

```
CAST (t0.isRefused as INTEGER)
```

So MySQL throws an error.

I'd like to have :

```
CAST (t0.isRefused as SIGNED INTEGER)
```

... but I don't know how to do this.

So if someone here could help me to find a solution it'll be very pleasant :)

Thanks !

Julien

Comment: Related issue https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/1433